# Get different value based on changing valued on different cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to make a formula that would give me a different value depending on changing value of one cell which has data verifications allowing a list of values based on a source from another table. So, I need to get different list of values in cell "2" according to the value choosed in cell "1". See screenshot of the data:

[image]

I tried it using an IF function, but it is way hard for me to connect it somehow with the data verifications in the cell.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with some sample data and the expected result. Otherwise it's pretty hard to help.

Comment: You can use a helping worksheet, There you write President => "Corresponding cell" // Projects => "Corresponding cell" and then just use a vlookup in your first sheet to find the corresponding result.